# Using laravel old function within a vuejs component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vuejs component that contains a form, I want to use the laravel old function so I'm able to repopulate the input fields if the form validation fails.

My guess would be I'd need to do something like pass the old function in as a prop to the component possibly but not sure if this is the 'right' way of doing it.

I'm just looking for confirmation on the best way of doing this.

Comment: The right way is pretty subjective, but I'd ask why you need to use `old()` in the vue component.  Most people use Vue with ajax requests, so the old value would still be in the form upon submission.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using ajax requests then yes the only way is to pass them as props. Probably send the whole array as one prop: `<component :oldInputs="{{old()}}"></component>`

Comment: HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalents